# How can I get updates about a LoCo team?

Tags: community, locoteams

I wanted to join to Ubuntu LoCo team in Jordan but the team is inactive and it seems that in this status since 2008, what is the solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can contact the Ubuntu Loco Community Council from their Launchpad page or Community council.

https://launchpad.net/~communitycouncil