# How can I give an idea to the ubuntu team?

Tags: community, canonical

Sorry for my simple question but it is important . I have many ideas for ubuntu . How can I give them all to ubuntu team . Is there Any webpage for that Or just an email ?

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/396752/how-can-i-get-updates-about-a-loco-team

Comment: Note that Ubuntu is more than just Canonical.

Answer (score -1):

Visit http://www.ubuntu.com/about/contact-us:

> Web feedback
>
> If you have suggestions or corrections for ubuntu.com or
>   canonical.com, email us at **webmaster@ubuntu.com** or
>   **webmaster@canonical.com**.

For contributing to community visit:http://community.ubuntu.com/contribute/

For joining LoCo Teams visit:http://loco.ubuntu.com/teams/

Comment: This only apply to the Webpages. Nothing about the software.

Comment: @Braiam But obviously the question has also nothing to do with any software!